# Get ServerRelativeUrl from Full Url -CSOM

Tags: csom, url

How to get ServerRelativeUrl from Full Url in CSOM code. In server side code SPWeb.GetServerRelativeUrlFromUrl() method which accepts a full, server-relative or site-relative URL as a parameter and returns the server-relative URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code will return the ServerRelativeUrl:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(fullURL);
string serverRelativeURL = uri.AbsolutePath;
```